# Displaying true colours in osX for cocoa applications

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, colors

**Context:**

I am displaying a window filled with the colour Red (255,0,0) in an OSX application. I am also doing a screen grab when this window is being displayed. Now, when I read the values of the pixel where the window was painted, I see that values of the pixels is actually 251,0,7.

I suspected that something is getting messed up while I am doing the screen grab, so I used the digital color utility in mac to check the colour and I got the same value - 251,0,7.

Which points that there is something happening when I am rendering the image. So, I tried out one more experiment as follows: created an image filled with red colour (255,0,0) across all pixels, exported it as a png and opened it in the image viewer of the mac. On this image, which is rendered by the OS itself, I ran the digital color meter and I still got 251,0,7 as the pixel value.

At this point, I thought, maybe this is just something Mac does - but as a last experiment, i mailed the image to myself and opened it using the image viewer in gmail and I see that <strike>Now the digital color meter shows a value of 255,0,0 for the pixels in the image - which means, somehow, google's image viewer could render the exact colours - so it is possible to show the exact colours.</strike> although reds are displayed correctly (255,0,0), green and blue are not correct.

**Question:**

Can someone point me to resources/code that demonstrates how to display true colours in Mac? In other words, is there way to display colours in the window, such that, when I do a screengrab of the displayed window, i get the exact same colours as I painted?

Updates:

Adding the image I am using.

[image]

Code that I am using right now:

```
 NSRect windowRect = {200,200,200,200};//{m_windowOriginX, m_windowOriginY, m_windowSizeX, m_windowSizeY};

m_NSWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:windowRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];

[m_NSWindow setTitle:@"overlayWindow"];

[m_NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];

g_imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0,0,200,200)];

[m_NSWindow.contentView addSubview:g_imageView];



NSColor *backgroundColor = [m_NSWindow backgroundColor];

backgroundColor = [NSColor clearColor];

[m_NSWindow setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];



[m_NSWindow setOpaque:YES];

//[m_NSWindow setAlphaValue:1.0];



naivePremultiplyRGBAMat(m_paintBuffer);

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextRef bitmapContext =  CGBitmapContextCreate(m_paintBuffer.data, 200, 200, 8, 800, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

CFRelease(colorSpace);



CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);



CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);
```

Here `naivePreMultiplyRGBAMat` is a custom function I wrote to pre-multiply the alpha component.

```
NSSize imageSize = NSMakeSize(200,200);

NSImage* myImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage: cgImage  size: NSMakeSize(

                    CGBitmapContextGetWidth(bitmapContext),

                    CGBitmapContextGetHeight(bitmapContext))];


[g_imageView setImage:myImage];
```

Comment: Won't the display color profiles affect that?

Comment: Good point. In which case, will it be possible to figure out what transformation the current display color profile is applying on the rendered colour, programmatically? This way, at least I would know what colour I should expect in the screengrab. Right now, I give it colour X, hoping I will get color X in the screengrab also, but what I get is a different colour, X', which messes with the rest of my logic

Comment: I suspect so, however that is beyond my knowledge. [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2313/_index.html) looks interesting, however.

Comment: Also, it seems like viewing the image through gmail, works fine. So, I was hoping there is some way to do it uniformly.

Comment: If you're drawing using NSColor, then the "device" colors give raw device RGB values, whereas the "calibrated" colors give RGB values using display color profiles etc.  I think CGColor has the same sort of stuff going on.  If you want to know how to change your code to give you raw device RGB values, you might want to actually post your code here.  :->

Comment: @bhaller Added the code. I think I am currently using raw device RGB values itself.

Comment: Interesting.  Well, I'm out of my depth on this, but perhaps others will have ideas.  The only suggestion I have is that perhaps the use of CGContext, NSImage, etc. is complicating things.  If this problem happens for a simple NSView that responds to drawRect: by doing NSRectFill() after setting the color with colorWithDeviceRed:green:blue:alpha:, then that code would perhaps be easier to get traction on.  Who knows what all that context/image machinery is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: As for your question "In which case, will it be possible to figure out what transformation the current display color profile is applying on the rendered colour, programmatically? This way, at least I would know what colour I should expect in the screengrab."  It seems like you have just written the code to figure that out, no?  Fill with red, do your screen grab, and the color values that you get are what you can expect to get.  Even if you can't figure out who is altering your RGB values or why, you ought to be able to work with that, perhaps...

Comment: @bhaller Yes, but that method just gives me the expected value for one color for one particular machine. I tried the same experiment on another iMac and I get some other values. So, I guess, it is not a usable solution. 
[this](http://ricciadams.com/articles/osx-color-conversions) link sort of explains why this problem is cropping up.

Comment: "just gives me the expected value for one color for one particular machine" – I'm saying do it at runtime, not at compile time.  Your program could do a quick test to find out the expected color value on the machine it is currently running on, and then work with that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem of not getting the same colors in screenshot/digital color meter as was present in the raw data of my image is explained by color profiles. Basically, if I say, I have RGB values of 255,0,0 it has no meaning unless I associate it with a color profile. When I am going to display the image on mac, there are three different buffers through which this image will pass and each of these buffers have an associated color profile.

The first buffer is image buffer itself, which is created by the following lines of code in the code I posted above:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextRef bitmapContext =  CGBitmapContextCreate(m_paintBuffer.data, 200, 200, 8, 800, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
```

Here the `colorSpace` variable is setting the color profile for this color space.

The second buffer is window buffer for which I can specify the the color space using the following code:

`[m_NSWindow setColorSpace: [NSColorSpace genericRGBColorSpace]]`

and the third buffer is the monitor itself which might have some color space associated with it - which you can change by going in the system preference and then selecting displays.

So, now, when I am sending my image through this pipeline (Image buffer to window buffer to monitor buffer), appropriate color conversions take place if each of these buffers have different color profiles. So, your color valus of `r,g,b` in the image buffer might get transformed to `r',g',b'` by the time it reached the monitor buffer.

Moreover, when you copy whatever is there in the monitor buffer to the buffer which corresponds the to the screen grab, another conversion will happen and the values that you finally read are these values.

Now, a straightforward way to ensure that you have the same values in the image buffer with the source image and image buffer with the screengrab is to ensure that both of them have the same colour profile. However, I would suggest that you maintain the same colour profile throughout all the buffers in your pipeline (window/monitor etc.) because there is loss of information when you convert from colour profile A to colour profile B and back to colour profile A.